# Data type conversion from Access to SQL Server errors

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, sqldatatypes

I have a SQL Server that is ODBC into my Access which is being utilized as my front end. I created a column in SQL with a BIT data type and created a checkbox with the yes/no data type that uses my SQL Column as its control source. When I go into my form and try to change anything in there and update my tables, I get a writing error and it wont let me append the updates I'm trying to make. As soon as I delete the bit data type, and the check box, then I am able to again append information to my form. Does anyone know a solution or a way I could utilize the Boolean check boxes to report to my SQL Database so that I could track progress of an order, but still be able to append my records? Also if anyone knows why this is happening I would appreciate the information just for my own notes and understanding.

this image shows the column created in SQL Server

[image]

This image shows what it looks like in the ODBC table in Access

[image]

This image shows the control source I picked which is from a query that utilizes the names of the form comboboxes, text boxes, and hopefully check boxes

[image]

This is image shows what happens after I try to update and and close

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Your posting is devoid of details. You say you get an error, but you don't post it. We can't help you without the actual error messages.

Comment: Also please post your code where you bind the chekboxes to your ODBC source.

Comment: It should not pose a problem. Do you have a timestamp field in the table and do you relink after changing the table design?

Comment: I have added what images I could to try to show this error. Hope this helps

Comment: Consider using an ADP instead of a MDB....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been messing around with this and after a few other problems running through SQL, Cabinet Vision (our drafting software with a ancient access database) and crystal reports I came to realize that Access cannot accept null values.

So in my SQL Bit data type column I set the default value as 0 and didn't allow nulls. now it records all my check boxes as true or false. and I no longer have a write conflict.

Answer (score 0):

haven't done this for a long time, but the problem could be related to the numbers that are stored. yes/no in access = -1/0, in sqlsrvr = 1/0 (or similar). you could use an INT field in sqlsrvr which will then store whatever access sends (-1 or 0), or keep the BIT but don't use yes/no in access - create a custom yes/no table where yes=1 and no=0 (or whatever BIT needs) and use the custom table as a lookup table for that field which, when updated will send the appropriate value. hope that's all relevant and makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This most commonly arises when a db is developed in Access and at some later date the tables are exported via ODBC to SQLServer.  The Checkbox controls on the Access forms were probably placed there using the 'Available Fields' button on the Access 'Design'  ribbon.  Before getting into complicated solutions with T-SQL modifications to metadata etc, try simply deleting the checkbox control from the problem Access form.  Insert an unbound checkbox to replace it, then use the the Properties dialog to set the relevant SQLServer field as the control source for that checkbox.  Usually works.